# How to scrape links without href attribute?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract links but there is not any href attribute given. How do I scrape the links from the page?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
for count in range(1,421):

r = requests.get('http://iapsm.org/MemberPage/members.php? 
page='+str(count)+'&Search=',headers= {'User-Agent':'Googleboat'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

links = soup.find_all('div',class_='Table')
for link in soup.find_all('tr'):
   c = (link.get('a'))
   print c
```

I'm not getting any output or getting any error

Comment: Can you upload the page which you are scraping and point out the links which you want?

Comment: Change `for link in soup.find_all('tr')` to `for link in links.find_all('tr')`

Comment: i want to scrap the member details given after opening view block @SauravPanda

Comment: it is bootstrap modal@SauravPanda

Answer (score 0):

To scrape all the details, first search for all the div which have there class as `modal-content`

You can try my code below to get all the information of users.

```
modals = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'modal-content'})
user_data = []
for modal in modals:
    uls = modal.find_all('ul',{'class':'Modal-List'})
    info = {}
    for ul in uls:
        info[ul[0]] = ul[1]
    user_data.append(info)
print(user_data)
```

Comment: Hey buddy, I want to scrap the the view tag links  of each doctor to open popup window , help me plz bro.

Comment: These buttons don't have a link, they are a javascript based modal button. Too open  the pop-up window, you need to use selenium. 
As far as tags are concerened, each button has a `data-target="#myModal_1" for first item and so on. `